# Alternative definition of a sample?

Tags: sampling, sample, definition

From my little knowledge of statistics, a sample is a subset of a population. Now I am reading a textbook on mathematical statistics. In the introductory section of the chapter on sampling distribution, the author gave another definition of a sample which I do not really understand intuitively.

***Definition:*** A sample is a set of observable random variables $X_1, \cdots , X_n$. The number $n$ is called the sample size.

Does this mean a sample can be uniquely determined by its set of random variables? This sounds more like a theorem to me than a definition.

**EDIT** Here is a link to that textbook and the definition in question is in Chapter 4.1: http://www.mim.ac.mw/books/Mathematical%20statistics%20with%20applications.pdf

Comment: It's a definition from a mathematical perspective. The idea of a sample is itself more complicated than some introductory definitions imply. First off, the population could be hypothetical and infinite. Even with coins and dice we could imagine tossing them again and again, indefinitely. With say a time series it can be fruitful to think of it as a sample, but the idea of a population is less useful than an idea that there is an underlying process.  If you measure rainfall and wheat yield at various places in a year, or at the same place over several years, what precisely is the population?